# How to add html tag inside plain text of javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, tags, anchor

I have the following variable in javascript code which displays plain text on a popup message of website.

```
"message": "This website is using browser cookies as per our internal cookie 
policy and privacy policy. By entering our website, you acknowledge that you 
have read and understood our privacy policy",
```

I am trying to make 'privacy policy' show as hyperlink by adding anchor tags to them. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What kind of popup message are you using?

Comment: cookieconsent. It only has option to add hyperlink to the last 'privacy policy'  of the text by adding a 'link' variable. But I would like to also add a hyperlink in the privacy policy text in the middle of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
var msg = '<h1>Message</h1>'
```

In order Web Browser converts it to HTML, you need to use `document.write()` method.

Comment: I have tried the following but didn't work:

    "message": "This website is using browser cookies as per our internal cookie 
    policy and <a href="/privacy-policy"> privacy policy</a>.

Comment: Because you used it wrong. Correct one: `"This website is using browser cookies as per our internal cookie policy and <a href='/privacy-policy'> privacy policy</a>."`

See how the quotation marks are written.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`elements`](https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/javascript-api/#custom_options) instead of the [`content`](https://cookieconsent.insites.com/documentation/javascript-api/#content_options) property of the cookieconsent library. So use

```
elements: {
  message: 'This website is using browser cookies as per our internal cookie policy and <a href="/privacy-policy"> privacy policy</a>.'
}
```

Instead of

```
content: {
  message: 'This website is using browser cookies as per our internal cookie policy and <a href="/privacy-policy"> privacy policy</a>.'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think you are trying to do something like this?
Instead of appending it to the body append it to your popup and change the href attribute to what you need.

```js
var policy = document.createElement('a');
var t = document.createTextNode('message: This website is using browser cookies as per our internal cookie policy and privacy policy. By entering our website, you acknowledge that you have read and understood our privacy policy');     // Create a text node
policy.appendChild(t);  
policy.setAttribute('href', "http://google.com");
document.body.appendChild(policy);
```

```html
<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```